# Tell Python to wait/pause a 'for' loop

Tags: python, loops

I have a Python program that navigates me to a website with a function that I have defined as nav(a, b), and on this site I will be downloading some pyfits data for use on another script. This site has a different pyfits file for every set of (a,b) in a catalog I have.

I was wondering if I could iterate through this catalog using a `for` loop, and each time the nav(a, b) function is used, tell python to pause while I download the file, then resume again when I tell it to. I've done something like this in [IDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDL_%28programming_language%29) before, but don’t know how with Python.

Otherwise I guess I'm stuck running the program 200 times, replacing the (a, b) values each time, which will take for ever.

Comment: Please post your code for `nav`. Are you downloading with `urllib2` or something like that?

Comment: Do you know where the file will be downloaded? If so you could list the directory before `nav`, then have Python poll the directory waiting for a new file to appear, then, possibly wait for the file's size to stop changing or some other measure of "it's downloaded".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to wait for a manual signal to continue, wait for the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

Python 2:

```
raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

Python 3:

```
input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

If you can download the file in the python code, do that instead of doing the manual task for each of the files.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [time.sleep()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) to pause the execution for t seconds:

```
import time
time.sleep(1.3) # Seconds
```

Demo:

```
import time

print "Start Time: %s" % time.ctime()
time.sleep(5)
print "End Time: %s" % time.ctime()
```

#### Output

```
Start Time: Tue Feb 17 10:19:18 2009
End Time: Tue Feb 17 10:19:23 2009
```

Comment: That has the minor problem of knowing how much time it takes to download the file. :)

Answer (score 10):

Use a `while` loop, waiting for your download to finish:

```
for ... :
    nav(a,b)
    while downloading_not_finished:
         time.sleep(X)
```

So, every X period of time a condition is tested, and is tested again until the downloading part is finished.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, here are two ways to pause in Python.

1. You can use the input function.

   ```
    # Python 2
    raw_input("Downloading....")

    # Python 3
    input("Downloading....")
   ```

This will pause the program until the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, etc.

2. You can use the time.sleep() function.

   ```
    import time
    time.sleep(number of seconds)
   ```

This will pause the Python script for however many seconds you want.

Answer (score 1):

For **Python shell** in design:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

try:
    shell = sys.stdout.shell
except:
    print('Run It In Shell')
dots = '........';
shell.write('Downloading')
sleep(0.5)
for dot in dots:
    shell.write(dot)
    sleep(0.1)
shell.write('\n')
sleep(0.4)
shell.write('Saving Files')
sleep(0.5)
for doot in dots:
    shell.write(dot)
    sleep(0.1)
shell.write('\n')
sleep(0.4)
```

For Python in a console:

```
from time import sleep

print('Downloading')
sleep(1)
print('Saving Files')
sleep(1)
```

Comment: What does "design" refer to? Running a .py file? Something to do with web ([Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29)/[Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29))? Running from within some IDE, like [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [input](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#input) function. It will pause the program until the prompt has been closed/filled in.

Comment: that sound like what i want to do. Is there a guide on how to use it?

Comment: Just search for the Python input function, or use this link http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_Output

It is the equivalent of using C#'s Console.ReadLine function, the program will wait for the user to type into the console and press return and pauses execution until then.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is to put another while loop inside the existing while loop:

```
while True:
#do something
asleep = True
while (asleep):
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 32: #Wait for space key  
        asleep = False
```